# Symfony 3 : No route found for "GET /lucky/controller"

Tags: routes

I'm new to Symfony and wanted to start with Symfony3. I followed the tutorial until I got to 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html#creating-a-page-route-and-controller
And then I kept having a 404 error on the route `/lucky/controller` using the URL`http://mywebsite/web/app_dev.php/lucky/controller`.

I tried with symfony2 and it is working correctly.
Here is the route (unchanged) :

`app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation`

Here is the controller :

```
    namespace AppBundle\Controller;

    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

    class LuckyController
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/lucky/number")
         */
        public function numberAction()
        {
            $number = rand(0, 100);

            return new Response(
                    '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
            );
        }
    }
```

Help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tutorial we have route @Route("/lucky/number") and you using /lucky/controller.
Can you show your controller?

Comment: I added the controller. Sorry for the delay !

Comment: I've actually never felt so dumb in my life ... Thanks Vlad I just realised the mistake -_-
And it works ...

Comment: If it makes you feel better, you're not alone: I am at least equally dumb, having made the exact same error. Which at least suggests we're both being led astray by a rogue tutorial or something.